# Java 17 module project (maven), when reading Json NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/json/JsonConfig$KeyStrategy

Tags: java, json, module, yasson

This is not my first module based project but I am very shakey on how it all works, I am sure this is my issue.  Project Jigsaw seems like smoke and mirrors to me at the moment.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is where the exception happens:

```
result.payload().ifPresent(payloadString -> {

        final var jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(payloadString));
        final var jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject(); <== error here
        jsonReader.close();
```

My module-info.java

```
    module com.mymodule.pocclient {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires jcip.annotations;
    requires java.logging;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires jakarta.json.bind;
    requires jakarta.json;
    requires org.eclipse.yasson;
    requires org.eclipse.parsson;
    requires static lombok;
    requires jjwt.api;
    requires com.mymodule.cryptography;


    opens com.mymodule.pocclient.controllers to javafx.fxml;
    opens com.mymodule.pocclient.model to javafx.base, org.eclipse.yasson;
    opens com.mymodule.pocclient to javafx.fxml;
    opens com.mymodule.pocclient.network to org.eclipse.parsson;

    exports com.mymodule.pocclient;
    exports com.mymodule.pocclient.controllers;
}
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/json/JsonConfig$KeyStrategy
at org.eclipse.parsson@1.1.0/org.eclipse.parsson.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$DuplicateStrategy.<clinit>(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:373)
at org.eclipse.parsson@1.1.0/org.eclipse.parsson.JsonObjectBuilderImpl.<init>(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:59)
at org.eclipse.parsson@1.1.0/org.eclipse.parsson.JsonParserImpl.getObject(JsonParserImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.parsson@1.1.0/org.eclipse.parsson.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:103)
at com.lifelenz.poclifelenzclient/com.mymodule.pocclient.controllers.LoginController.lambda$processAuthenticatedUser$0(LoginController.java:121)
```

dependencies from my pom file (not sure how much is relevant)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.lifelenz.jmsa</groupId>
        <artifactId>cryptography</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.parsson</groupId>
        <artifactId>parsson</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.jcip</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcip-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>11.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried it without all this module stuff?

Comment: This is the direction that Java wants us to go, so it is my intention to resolve this not give up.

Comment: I did not say that you should give up but it is good practice to split up problems into smaller ones that you can then investigate step by step. In your case the problem may be a missing maven dependency and/or a missing module dependency. So, if you can exclude the first you can then concentrate on the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the following dependency resolved the issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I assume it was clashing with parsson.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the `jakarta.json-api` in a version higher or equal `2.1.0` (`JsonConfig` class was introduced in version `2.1` of jakarta jsonb implementation)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```